# Cortana Skill filtering time information when passing message to Bot Framework v4

Tags: botframework, cortana, cortana-skills-kit

When I invoke my **Cortana skill** and say *"Ask MyBot find me a meeting room from 10:00 AM to 11:00 AM"*, it is understood correctly and shown on the Cortana canvas.

**However**, the message I receive on bot side is *"find me a meeting room from 10"*.

The same happens when I say *"Ask MyBot book me a room tomorrow 10:00 o'clock"*. Bot receives *"book me a room tomorrow 10"*.

So all time related pieces of the utterance seem to be filtered out by Cortana and just the first number is appended.

When I type the above directly into the Cortana canvas instead of speaking it, then the full text is received by the bot.

Is the speech model of Cortana somehow filtering the input wrong? I've already checked my speech priming settings, but I haven't selected any model.

The only thing I can think of is that regional settings somehow interfere here, but I have not idea where it might come from. The device it self is all set to en-US.

**Update**

Did some more tests and speaking "Ask MyBot 9:30 AM" does result in "9" on bot site. So I think that somehow everything after **:** is removed and I believe it must be on the channel logic as it doesn't happen when using text, even over Cortana canvas directly.

Thus I've filed a bug report on the [bot services GitHub page](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Services/issues/65).

Comment: I would be interested to see the dump of the message your bot receives, as numbers, dates, and times are built in intents with cortana. "FInd me a meeting room for 10" would have a number intent.

Answer (score 0):

I've reproduced the defects and filed tickets on the appropriate teams. Thanks for reporting this.

Comment: To unblock in your development try turn 1 instead of turn 0.  That means instead of "ask bot to book meeting between 10:30 am and 11:30 am", "0: open bot", "1: book meeting between 10:30 am and 11:30 am"